# Is it possible that the service still runs after the app got killed with task manager?

Tags: java, android

Hello im triying to run a service in background that it doesn't stop when app is destroyed by task manager. The idea of the service is verify every "x" min if there a new insert in a database that i got in a server.

The service is running great even if i close the app but when i use the task manager to destroy my app all the threads are closed too.

So i want to know if its possible to run a thread that ask in background forever unless user cancel it in the app itself, that ignore the destroy caused by task manager so in the future i can use notification bar to tell the user that a new insert happened in the database.

**Tryed:**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               askServer(); // i made a timertask that ask every "x" minute 


     return START_STICKY;
}
```

As i read START_STICKY should run again the service if it get killed for some reason and i know that this can be done since some app get closed by taskmanager and still get notifications from it as whatsapp,bbms and others. Please tell me if im wrong in anything and thank you for reading!.

---

**UPDATE**: Im not trying to break any law or security rule from Android and im not trying to ignore the stoping services option from an app in settings. I want that the service that listen for new incoming "events " inserts in my case keep running after user used the interface that appear when you press home for a while :

[image]

---

**UPDATE** : sorry for talking to much about this app but is the one that i can use as an example. In whatsapp when i close the app by the interface that i showed above the process and services are killed but after a couple of second they relaunch, this is exactly what i want to do to keep user informed about database events. From setting you still can stop the service without problem or even i can put the option in the app itself to stop notifiying.

Is a bad implementation call in OnDestroy() method an instance of the service so it relaunch after destroy?

---

**UPDATE** : welp looks like my service is still running on background after i close the app. I will just have to work on my service design to not waste battery life and resources. Also i was using the log.i()  to check if service was running, looks like when main process closes i can't use log or toast just notifications ( still not implemented) because the service is there running just won't show in log .

---

**UPDATE** : now is working using using startForeground(0, null). In future i will send a notification to show when a event on database happen building it and calling startForeground(1, notification).

Comment: 'that ignore the destroy caused by task manager' - I hope not, it would be a massive security problem.

Comment: @MartinJames is there a way to do so without compromising security?. I have seen apps that use notifications even if the app itself is closed and not running in taskmanager.

Comment: An app that is merely not running can start from certain triggers.  But one which has been killed by the user from the settings menu cannot do anything until explicitly started by the user.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well im not talking about kill it from settings, in android when you press home for a couple of seconds an interface appear with the apps that are running . For example when im running whatsapp i click on home for a while and then this interface appear showing all the activites open if i take whatsapp and slide it to a side its closes.

Comment: Even if do so, in settings you can see that whatsapp still have 2 process and 1 service running, this service is MessageService. From there you can stop the service and its the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For services, look at Settings -> Applications -> Services. and see if it is running.
 However, poorly designed services may run more often or perform syncing operations. So yes it is possible.

Comment: welp looks like my service is still running on background after i close the app. I will just have to work on my service design to not waste battery life and resources. Also i was using the log.i()  to check if service was running, looks like when main process closes i can't use log or toast just notifications ( still not implemented) because the service is there running just won't show in log .

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this when developing my first android game; force-stop was the only way to kill it.

`START_NOT_STICKY` will kill the background service when you swipe the app away from the task manager. `START_STICKY` is, as the name implies, "sticky", Meaning it sticks to the android system even when the app is gone.

That's from my experience, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've never answered a question before! Always open to learn.